# Ampere's Law: Any surface? But what about these? There must be some requirements right?

Tags: electromagnetism

I was a bit confused by the fact that we can use a surface of any boundary for Ampere's law; especially when it comes to capacitance.

Consider the standard model of the capacitor used to *derive* the need for displacement current. Then Ampere's law, if we use the disk bounded by a circle with radius less than the plates, should have magnitude $$B = \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi} \frac{r}{R^2} i_C$$ [image: From Sear's and Zermansky's University Physics]

according to my textbook. I completely understand the derivation there. But since Ampere's law could be the boundary of any surface, why couldn't we just make it into a bulging one with the same circular boundary, but with a surface which passes through the plates passes through plates and encompasses the current $i_C$ (surface 1)?

It feels wrong because the surface is intersecting a plate, but I read somewhere that *any* surface works; So, why not this one? Then only $i_C$ passes through the current, and $B$ in that reduced radius wouldn't need that factor.

What's stopping us from making a surface with that boundary that just bulges out wide then contracts (surface 2)? For more context, I'll describe what I'm thinking with some pictures below.

[image]

I know there must be some misunderstanding on my part on the whole idea of bounding a surface, or there are some requirements on the surface that I'm missing, but someone please explain.

Comment: Made some edits for easier reading

Comment: Surface-2 can't be easily distinguished from surface-1. A suggestion is to label surfaces as $S_1$ and $S_2$

Comment: Hm. I uncapitalized the "according" since it's part of the previous sentence. I appreciate the other stylistic edits a lot, though. As for the surfaces, I'll see what I can do. Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is not even about the ampere's law but rather the nature of current through the plate of capacitor and finding a notion of the field in there

Comment: No. I completely understand that. My issue is with the mathematics, specifically regarding Stoke's theorem. The derivation of the need for Ampere's law required showing contradictions between two surfaces with the same boundary, but here, with my new surfaces, I've found a similar contradiction, which shouldn't exist. Under my two (albeit irregular) surfaces, the current passing through is $i_C$, so the field should be $B = \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi} \frac{1}{R} i_C$. But if we take the surface to be a disk, we obtain the result I presented in my question. So I'm confused on the *surfaces* allowed.

Comment: perhaps you should explicitly write that other result in the subejct of question

Comment: Hm. Perhaps. I'm a bit tired right now, so I'll wait a little to see how people respond.

Comment: This is a nice wrinkle on a familiar example. (Possible future exam question...)

Comment: I think students like me have a lot of trouble imaging the fact that *every surface* works (as long as it's closed and has the boundary we define), so really drilling that in I think would be helpful :))

Comment: Well I thought the main point of your question was that you understood that is *must* work, but you couldn't understand how the RHS was modified to match the fixed LHS - not that you wanted a proof of Stokes' theorem, which can be found anywhere.

Comment: Yah, that is exactly right. To rephrase, I think a lot of students come up with these sorts of special "contradictions" and get confused by them since they *know* they must have some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ampere's law *does* work for those surfaces too. What you have forgotten about is (i) the non-zero conduction current *in the plates* for surface 1; (ii) the non-zero displacement current term over surface 2. Both of these terms contribute negatively to the RHS of Ampere's law and hence match the $r^2/R^2$ reduction factor in the derived B-field between the plates at a distance $r$ from the centre line.

Ampere's law is not that the closed line integral of the B-field equals the enclosed current; it is that it is equal to the sum of the enclosed current and the enclosed displacement current terms - that is the whole point of the capacitor example. i.e.
$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} = \mu_0 \left(I_c + I_d\right)\ .$$

Let's simplify surface 1 to be a cylinder extending from your loop of radius $r$ so that it ends outside the plates. (See below for a sketch).

[image: Sketch]

For an ideal capacitor the electric field lines and the rate of change of electric field are parallel and run between the plates, so for surface 1 as shown above, the E-field would always be tangential to that part of the cylinder's curved surface between the plates and since there is also no electric field outside the plates there would be no displacement current term at all. However, there is obviously still the $I_c$ conduction current through the flat face of the cylinder contributing to the RHS of Ampere's law case, so how can we square that with the smaller value of the toroidal B-field for the Amperian loop between the plates?

Well, what you cannot assume is that there is zero conduction current in the plates themselves. For example if the capacitor plates are circular with radius $R$ and your circular path is of radius $r$, then a fraction $(R^2 -r^2)/R^2$ of the charge on the plates lies outside the cylindrical surface I defined above. But if the charge on the plates is changing with time there must be a net current flowing from the outer part of the plates to the inner part and then into the wire (shown as a blue current density in the picture). This will be a *negative term* on the RHS of Ampere's law because it flows *into* the cylindrical surface, and will be of size $I(r^2 -R^2)/R^2$. The sum of the conduction current terms is therefore smaller and indeed will match the reduced B-field between the plates at radius $r$ compared with the field you would expect for a similar loop outside the plates.

For surface 2 the solution is different. The surface does not cut through the plates at all so there is no additional conduction current term. However here there *is* a negative displacement current contribution due to the integral of the rate of change of E-field over that part of surface 2 which is between the plates. It is a negative contribution because the E-field lines are going *into* surface 2 between the plates. Again, a careful calculation would show that this negative displacement current plus the conduction current that exits surface 2 outside the plates is exactly what is required to balance the smaller LHS of Ampere's law for the small loop of radius $r$ between the plates.

Comment: Ah, but here I was also confused. If there is a displacement current *added*, then why is the value derived from a disk, what I have above, *less* than that which comes from considering $i_C$ which passes through the surfaces, mainly $B = \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi} \frac{1}{r} i_C$ (as if the wire weren't even there)? That's what I was confused. There must be some negative? But how does that work?

Comment: @mijucik  As I say in my answer, for surface 2, the displacement current term is negative because the E-field lines are going *into* the surface you have defined.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I missed that part. That makes so much more sense! Thank you :)

Comment: Are you saying there is a displacement current per area density between capacitor plates in the last paragraph?  Also could you explain this part "Surface 1 is more interesting, especially if you just make it a cylinder poking out from the plates, such that the E-field is always tangential to the surface between the plates, since then there is no displacement current term at all. " I'm having a hard time visualizing the cylinder that you are referring too, I think a picture will help.

Comment: Just to clarify, the (and forgive me if I'm using this term wrong) *induced* current in the internal plates is in the opposite direction of $i_C$ right? So I can think of a small current of the value you derived as a mini one within the plates in the opposite direction?

Comment: @mijucik The RHS of Ampere's law is a surface integral. If the current flows into the surface it is negative, if it flows out its is positive.  For the RH plate (with the negative charge) the direction of conventional current flow in the wire is away from the plate. The direction of the current in the plate is from outside to in. Thus this latter current flows *into* the surface 1 (so negative), while the current in the wire flows out (positive).

Comment: Ah. I see. I wish my introductory class to E+M elaborated more on the mathematics. I only know the basic form of $\int B \cdot dr = \mu_0 I_{enc}$ and not the surface integral formulation (though I have studied Calculus III). Thanks for elaborating and I'll look into it more.

Comment: "For that surface, the E-field would always be tangential to that part of the cylinder's surface between the plates and there would be no displacement current term at all"  I just read this several times then I realized we are not dealing with electrostatic and hence electric fields can curve to be tangential. However, How do you cylinders out surface would have E-field as tangential over the whole cap?

Comment: @Buraian The field lines are shown in the OP's diagram. They are straight. They are tangential to the curved surface of a cylinder extending from the circular path shown in the OP's diagram. The "cap" is outside of the plates and so is not included in my statement. The E-field is zero outside the capactor and does not contribute to the displacement current.

Comment: Oh now I get it, you were saying about curved surface area.

Answer (score 5):

You have understood something very important. It seems like a paradox that we  can use the surface through the capacitor through which no current passes.  This is the crucial observation  that lead to Maxwell to his equations.  The point is that the validity of Ampere's law requires an extra term
$$
{\bf J}\to {\bf J}+ \frac{\partial {\bf D}}{\partial t}
$$
where $ {\partial {\bf D}}/{\partial t}$ is Maxwell's  *displacement current*. Although there is  no current ${\bf J}$ between the plates, there is a displacement current, and once you include that you  get the same $\int {\bf H}\cdot d{\bf r}$  for every surface.

Without the displacement current there would be no electromagnetic waves. So Maxwell's (and now your) worry about this point is the birthplace  of all radio technology.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for this extra insight into displacement currents. I really appreciate it :) I was more confused about the seeming contradiction that occurs *when we assume displacement current to exist*. I know I didn't ask my question clear enough, but see my above comments to Rob to kinda understand it better. Thank you again though, I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 5):

This actually applies in any dimension, not just three.  It goes like this.

Circulation is a kind of idea, that if you put two loops side by side, each carrying the same current, the current down the common edges cancel out, and the two polygons merge into one.  Thus a figure can be built up, such that all of the polygons on the surface have currents that cancel out.

Each bit of surface, has an out-vector, which is proportional to the area.  A vector normal.  This vector, in a closed figure, is the 'gradient of density', or $\nabla D$.  The interesting thing here is that for a closed surface, $dV = \vec r \cdot d\vec S$ , which is the usual way of measuring volume (ie sum over the volume).

Since this is a moment (that is, the sum of vector elements over coordinates), and volume does not have a residual moment, then $\sum  d\vec S = 0$.

If we now divide the surface by a boundary, such as a loop, then there is a 'current' in the loop, and the two halves have an area-vector of $+A$ and $-A$, retaining the same value.  We can then replace $+A$ by any other surface that is bounded by the loop, and expect that it has a definite volume, and thus has the same vector area.

It works in all dimensions.  For example, given two points A and B, the vector sum of the perpendiculars to dS, segments of the line, must be constant (and equal to the length).  In four dimensions, a polyhedron made of clockwise faces, points 'down', and when two clockwise faces are placed together, they cancel out.

Comment: Wow. I've never seen it put like that. Thanks for the insight :0

Comment: Nor had I until i discovered the therom.

Comment: Do you remember what source you learnt it from? Just wondering ~

Comment: When I say i discovered it, it was brand new from my own hand.

Comment: Wow! Let me know if you've written a paper. I'd love to check it out! If you haven't, I just want you to know it's very interesting :))

Comment: I've scratched some ideas on http://www.os2fan2.com/ but as engineering goes, it's as plain as day.

Comment: " volume does not have a residual moment" , could you explain why this might be the case?

Comment: Ah. I'm just a freshman so maybe this seems way more complex than it is.

Comment: Moment in its basic sense, is $\xi V = \int x dv$, where V is the a thing the moment is taken of, and x is the vector position of dV.  They don't really explain dipole moments all that well, but that's what it means.  If the moment of V is zero, then it can be positioned anywhere, means that $\int dV = 0$,  It can still be a vector, just that it has a zero sum.

Comment: I wrote an awful lot when I was a freshman.

Comment: I'll try my best to do the same :)

Comment: Have a look at http://www.os2fan2.com/files/physics.pdf  It's a broken draft, but some of the chapters are pretty good.  It's about dimensional analysis, but we try to define the quantities we analyse and do a bit of unit history.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at it

Comment: What is the difference between $ \nabla D $ and $ dS$? Aren't both outward normals?

Comment: One thing bothering me is looks ike the quantity of volume looks like a vector from your equation because suppose you dot any two vectors then you get a scalar. Now that scales up the third vector which doesn't have anything to be dotted with

Comment: fixed the equations, the D was sperious.  $\nabla D = \vec S$